# How do I dynamically add multiple lines to a windows form tab?

Tags: winforms, tabs, windows-forms-designer, paintevent

I am trying to add a collection of lines to a tab dynamically, however after loading they do not continue to display correctly. Eventually I would like to have up to a few hundred.

Initially it will look like the first version but after scrolling the lines look like the second version.

[image]
[image]

In order to add these lines I have added a Paint event to the tab in the designer as:

`this.TabTree.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.PaintLines);`

And created a method

```
    private void PaintLines(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        int linesLen = Lines.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < linesLen; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, Lines[i].X1, Lines[i].Y1, Lines[i].X2, Lines[i].Y2);
        }
    }
```

This is based off the advise in here:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25024010/How-do-I-draw-a-line-on-the-page-of-a-tab-control.html

I think I am missing something about how Paint events work. I tried initially going through the main Paint event for the form but couldn't get the lines to show on the tab. I would also like to be able to delete and update the lines if possible.

If you can provide any information on how better to implement line drawing to a tab dynamically, or an alternative approach I would be very grateful. Maybe a way to clear the lines and redraw when a scroll event happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed a refresh event to occur. That can happen from a button as in the link below or in my case at a scroll event. New code:

```
    private void TabTree_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        TabTree.Refresh();
        scrollPos = e.NewValue;
    }

    private void PaintLines(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Drawing.Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        int linesLen = Lines.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < linesLen; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(penObj, Lines[i].X1, Lines[i].Y1 - scrollPos, Lines[i].X2, Lines[i].Y2 - scrollPos);
        }
    }
```

Helpful link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc5eXYwTROg